# Detect if NSString contains a URL and generate a "link" to open inside the app a Safari View

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsstring

I have am reading a twitter feed in my iPhone application and can do it correctly, but I'd like to evolve it in a way to detect if the whole NSString contains any URL or URLs and create a "link" that will open a UIWebView within the same application.

Can you guide me on how to perform this task?

```
-(void) setTextTwitter:(NSString *)text WithDate:(NSString*)date
{
    [text retain];
    [textTwitter release], textTwitter = nil;
    textTwitter = text;

    [date retain];
    [dateTwitter release], dateTwitter = nil;
    dateTwitter = date;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Craig Hockenberry's IFTweetLabel, which can be found [here](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/).

Or you can use the label provided by Three20 library, which can be found [here](http://github.com/facebook/three20).

Or the simplest solution: use UIWebView with dataDetectorTypes set to UIDataDetectorTypeLink.

Cheers, Paul

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pawel, actually I am using Three20 library but can't find an API function to identify links... can you point me to it? That'd be great.

Comment: As far as I remember you need to look for styleLabel (TTCatalog, StyledTextTableTestController, you'll be able to trace it from there). Cheers, Paul